# Android Things BLE Pairing not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things, pairing

I'm trying to pair my pi3 with android things to a BLE device.

Following
https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/bluetooth.html#device-pairing

I set a pairingCallback:

```
mBluetoothConnectionManager = BluetoothConnectionManager.getInstance();
mBluetoothConnectionManager.registerPairingCallback(mBluetoothPairingCallback);
```

this is my pairing callback:

```
private BluetoothPairingCallback mBluetoothPairingCallback = new BluetoothPairingCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPairingInitiated(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice,
                                   PairingParams pairingParams) {
        // Handle incoming pairing request or confirmation of outgoing pairing request
        Log.d(TAG,"onPairingInitiated");
        handlePairingRequest(bluetoothDevice, pairingParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaired(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
        // Device pairing complete
        Log.d(TAG,"onPaired");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnpaired(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
        // Device unpaired
        Log.d(TAG,"onUnpaired");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPairingError(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice,
                               PairingError pairingError) {
        // Something went wrong!
        Log.d(TAG,"onPairingError "+getPairingErrorVerbose(pairingError.getErrorCode()));
    }
};
```

and in handlePairingRequest:

```
private void handlePairingRequest(final BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, PairingParams pairingParams) {
    switch (pairingParams.getPairingType()) {
        case PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_DISPLAY_PIN:
        case PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_DISPLAY_PASSKEY:
            // Display the required PIN to the user
            Log.d(TAG, "Display Passkey - " + pairingParams.getPairingPin());
            break;
        case PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN:
        case PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN_16_DIGITS:
            // Obtain PIN from the user
            //String pin = ...;
            // Pass the result to complete pairing
            //mBluetoothConnectionManager.finishPairing(bluetoothDevice, pin);
            break;
        case PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_CONSENT:
        case PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION:
            // Complete the pairing process
            mBluetoothConnectionManager.finishPairing(bluetoothDevice);
            break;
    }
}
```

I get a PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_CONSENT and proceed with finishPairing.

My issue is that finishPairing changes the status from BOND_BONDING to BOND_BONDED but my device pairing is missing something and the device is not connected as it is in standard android (I have the same app for android mobile and the pairing is ok when the user accepts the pairing in the BluetoothPairingDialog).

It seems that in BluetoothPairingDialog it is performed     mDevice.setPairingConfirmation(true);
and its result is different from     mBluetoothConnectionManager.finishPairing(bluetoothDevice);

Am I missing something during the pairing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you doing Bluetooth or Bluetooth Low Energy? Related: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: I'm trying to pair with a Bluetooth Low Energy device